# How to make image maps on other servers in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Consider this picture:

[image: Image map minecraft]

I used an image to map converting tool which I found somewhere on GitHub.

The thing is, I saw an item just like this on a public Minecraft server. Somebody there offered to sell it to me. How did he/she do this on a server? He wasn't an admin or anything.

The only way I know of creating these 'image maps' are by modifying the map.dat files, which requires administrative privileges over the server/world.

Answer (score 4):

You can go through the painstaking work to place the appropriate blocks on a horizontal plane to make the maps.

Here I have placed down the blocks to make my name:
[image]

Comment: The easiest approach is to create the map in creative or using [a tool](https://rebane2001.com/mapartcraft/), then use a client-side mod like Litematica to rebuild it manually in the world.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the map in your own world, put it into your hotbar and save it (default C+number). Then on the server, you can restore the hotbar (default X+number), if you are in Creative mode.

Comment: K gonna test this